# PrestaShop 1.6 - Cannot override module tpl file in theme

Tags: themes, overriding, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to override the file

`modules/cheque/views/templates/hook/infos.tpl`

in my theme so that I can change the icon it displays because it's hardcoded however my override doesn't seem to work.

I've placed my overrided .tpl file in this directory:

`themes/mytheme/modules/cheque/views/templates/hook/infos.tpl`

I've also cleared the cached files in `cache/smarty/compile/*`

Am I missing something perhaps?

Comment: did you enabled compile on back?

Comment: yes I did force recompilation but it didn't work